# How to handle complex strings in internalization (i18n)?

Tags: javascript, internationalization

Let we have a sting `I want to by {number} apples`. And we have and interface:

[image: String with select tag inside.]

What is the best way to support with conditions:

- whole phrase should be a text
- `apples` could have plural form

How do solve this in your JavaScript-projects?

Comment: it depends on your web framework...

Comment: The main pits fall is a `<select>` tag inside translation phrase. And I'm wondering how it could look like in different frameworks.

Comment: that is way too broad

Answer (score 1):

You should create a data structure to store all these phrases and make a function which selects them based on conditions (not perfect solution, nor flawless javascript but might give you an idea):

```
var translations =
{
  "English":{
    "I want to by %n apples":[
      [0, "%n apples"],
      [1, "%n apple"],
      [2, "%n apples"]
    ]
  }
},
{
  "American":{
    "I want to by %n apples":[
      [0, "%n apples, dude"],
      [1, "%n apple, dude"],
      [2, "%n apples, dude"]
    ]
  }
};

var languageToUse = "American";
var stringToReplace = "I want to by %n apples";
var numberOfItems = 1;
var newEnding = translations[languageToUse][stringToReplace][numberOfItems];

var res = stringToReplace.replace("%n apples", newEnding);

// res = "I want to by %n apple, dude"
```

http://i18njs.com/ has excellent examples how to do this.

Comment: Your dummy example can't handle `numberOfItems = 4`. Also it is not clear how `var translations` should looks like with `<select>` inside.